# Get chrome folder path c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, path, directory

I need to get chrome folder path (AppData/Local/Chrome).
I try to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`, but this path to AppData/Roaming.

Comment: Installation folder of Chrome will not always in AppData, it may be Program Files too.

Comment: For `AppData` you can use `%AppData%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other answers before, I understand that You want to get the Chome's program data path, not program executable path.

For data path I use

```
string localAppDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string chromeLocalAppDataPath = localAppDataPath + @"\Google\Chrome"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find installation path of Chrome from this registry entry.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome`

```
                                OR
```

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome`

Use

```
Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, defaultValue)
```

to get a value from Registry.

Comment: This key doesn't exist for me on Windows 7 x64, Chrome 35.  `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process chromeProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome").FirstOrDefault();
if(chromeProcess != null)
{
  string path = process.Modules[0].FileName;
}
```

Comment: OP didn't mention whether Chrome is running or not while he executing his application. So, this answer is not an apt one.

Comment: @NK fair point, if the OP finds this a fitting solution then they will have to refine their initial question to prevent confusion